# What is the symmetry group of the standard sphere packing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, spheres

I know this is a very basic question, but I couldn't find an answer with Google:

What is the symmetry group of the usual sphere packing?

By the usual one, I mean the FCC lattice or HCP lattice. I am interested in both the rotation group and the group of all orthogonal symmetries. I can tell it has $48$ (or $96$ respectively) elements.

My reasoning for it having 48 elements is that - focusing only on the spheres touching the origin sphere - a sphere can be mapped to any of the twelve others. Say we map A to A′. Then a sphere adjacent to A can be mapped to any sphere adjacent to A′. I think there are 4 such spheres. That gives 12×4 possible choices. When reflections are allowed, there is an extra choice between the two spheres adjacent to both of those. Is this incorrect?

I'd be happy with just a link, as I'm sure its structure has been proven countless times elsewhere.

Comment: Note that a crystal structure/sphere packing also (usually) has translational symmetries, so it cannot be of finite order. What symmetry group are you after exactly? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry maybe? But that has half the elements you describe.

Comment: @student91 I'm interested in the symmetries that fix the sphere at the origin. Or equivalently, the symmetries that are contained in the orthogonal group.

Comment: @student91
My reasoning for it having 48 elements is that - focusing only on the spheres touching the origin sphere - a sphere can be mapped to any of the twelve others. Say we map $A$ to $A'$. Then a sphere adjacent to $A$ can be mapped to any sphere adjacent to $A'$. I think there are 4 such spheres. That gives $12 \times 4$ possible choices. When reflections are allowed, there is an extra choice between the two spheres adjacent to both of those.

Comment: You should make corrections by editing the question, not just in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres) that the centers of the spheres around a single sphere form either (the vertices of) a cuboctahedron (For FCC lattice), or a triangular orthobicupola (For HCP lattice). So the symmetry is either [octahedral symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry) or [triangular-prism-symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_symmetry_in_three_dimensions).

The order of this symmetry group is thus 48, not 96, because some spheres form triangles and other for squares, and you cannot put a triangle on a square, that is not a symmetry.